# Lanzar un acceso directo desde otra aplicacion

Tags: android

Estoy intentando lanzar una acceso directo desde una aplicación mía. Pero solo consigo lanzar el main,como puedo lanzar el acceso directo si no se las rutas.

esto me lanza el main:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("nombre_paquete", 
                             "nombre_MainActivity"));
     startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar únicamente el paquete de la aplicación para abrirla mediante  `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage()` , ejemplo:

```
    try{
            Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("<nombre_paquete>");
            if(i != null) {
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias. Pero haria lo mismo que cuando yo llamo al "package.Mainactivity. Para llamar a un acceso directo de esa aplicación,¿seria posible?